# Set bit depth in FFmpeg encoding for HEVC?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, hevc

FFmpeg is now [supporting](https://github.com/videolan/x265/blob/master/build/linux/multilib.sh) 10-bit and 12-bit encoding for x265, But I couldn't find the proper command line options for encode them in those bit depths.

Can someone specify that options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have an *appropriately configured* modern version of FFmpeg and x265, (the repository FFmpeg under Zesty Zapus 17.04 falls into this category), you should find encoding with 8, 10 and 12bit fairly straightforward.

I illustrate a sample command line for each below:

**1. 8bit HEVC encoding with FFmpeg...**

Check the capability of your installed version of x265 for *8bit encoding* as follows:

```
andrew@illium~$ x265 -V
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 2.4
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 7.1.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX XOP FMA4 FMA3 LZCNT BMI1
andrew@illium~$
```

Here you will see that my own copy has capabilities for 8|10|12 bit encoding. An installation of FFmpeg compiled against this version of x265 can produce a decent 8bit encode with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
       -c:a aac -b:a 128k \
       output_8bit.mp4
```

You can of course vary any of these settings to suit your specific needs...

**2. 10bit HEVC encoding with FFmpeg...**

Check the capability of your installed version of x265 for *10bit encoding* as follows:

```
andrew@illium~$ x265 -V -D10
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 2.4
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 7.1.0][64 bit] 10bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX XOP FMA4 FMA3 LZCNT BMI1
andrew@illium~$
```

Here you will see that my own copy has capabilities for 10 bit encoding. An installation of FFmpeg compiled against this version of x265 can produce a decent 10bit encode with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le \
       -c:a aac -b:a 128k \
       output_10bit.mp4
```

And this should see you through...

**3. 12bit HEVC encoding with FFmpeg...**

Check the capability of your installed version of x265 for *12bit encoding* as follows:

```
andrew@illium~$ x265 -V -D12
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 2.4
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 7.1.0][64 bit] 12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX XOP FMA4 FMA3 LZCNT BMI1
andrew@illium~$
```

Here you will see that my own copy has capabilities for 12bit encoding. An installation of FFmpeg compiled against this version of x265 can produce a decent 12bit encode with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p12le  \
       -c:a aac -b:a 128k \
       output_12bit.mp4
```

Once again experimentation with some of the *ancillary parameters* should give you exactly the results you are after...

**Notes:**

1. If you are unsure of which pixel formats (for the vital `-pix_fmt` FFmpeg setting) are supported by *your* copy of FFmpeg and libx265 the following command will show the details:

   ```
    ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265 2>/dev/null | grep pixel
   ```
2. [FFmpeg and H.265 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265): Base information on HEVC encoding with FFmpeg, nothing on 8|10|12 bit encoding though...
3. Zesty Zapus (17.04) has a slightly older but fully configured x265:

   ```
     andrew@ilium:~$ x265 -V
     x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 2.3
     x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 6.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
     x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX LZCNT
     andrew@ilium:~$
   ```

   and thus can encode to all 3 possible bit depths...

Comment: A quick shortcut to see bit depths that the compiled libx265 supports, is to run `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265 | grep pixel`. My build has `Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuv422p yuv444p gbrp yuv420p10le yuv422p10le yuv444p10le gbrp10le yuv420p12le yuv422p12le yuv444p12le gbrp12le gray gray10le gray12le`

Comment: @Mulvya That is great! I have added this into my answer, thanks :)

Comment: 10-bit HEVC works perfectly by ubuntu zesty default packages.

Comment: @DanialBehzadi Great to hear! What about 8 and 12 bit? I have not tested on Zesty with defaults...

Comment: @andrew.46 8-bit is default and works out of the box. I could encode 12-bits, but I was unable to decode it with Totem (Not supported) or VLC (Green Screen, but voice works).