# ffmpeg - How do I convert x265 10bit to x265 8bit

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

My media player does not support 10bit hevc content, how can I convert my 10bit hevc files to 8bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will require *re-encoding* with thus some loss of quality but a recent copy of FFmpeg will allow you to convert to 8bit hevc from 10bit quite easily.

I tested with the following 10bit sample:

```
andrew@illium~$ mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Format%:%BitDepth% bits" 10_bit.mkv
HEVC:10 bits
```

This sample was re-encoded as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i 10_bit.mkv \
       -c:v libx265 -preset medium -x265-params crf=28 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
       -c:a copy \
       8_bit.mkv
```

The [crucial option](https://askubuntu.com/q/922563/57576) here is: `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. The output file demonstrated a successful conversion to 8bit:

```
andrew@illium~$ mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Format%:%BitDepth% bits" 8_bit.mkv
HEVC:8 bits
```

If you can try and avoid re-encoding in this manner though, better to encode *from the original media file* thus avoiding some degradation of the image and loss of quality...

**References:**

- [Set bit depth in FFmpeg encoding for HEVC?](https://askubuntu.com/q/922563/57576) Some more details about setting the bit depth for hevc...